# How much memory do my Rails app and Postgres DB need in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-ec2

Is there a tool that can profile my rails app, and tell me how much Ram it needs to run in production, (taking the db and imagemagick into account).

The reason I ask is that I have a small rails app, which runs on Heroku's free tier, and I'd like to move it to EC2 or Rackspace, but want to know how much it's going to cost me, before I decide whether it's worth investing the time in doing this.

Comment: Cant you just run it locally and use "top" utility (or means of your own OS) to measure it?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. And if there is, I would not trust it. The best way to figure it out is to do load testing. If it was me, I would spin up a medium or small instance and start slamming the application and see at what point it dies. Then make tweaks to the application, the web-server, the caching layer, the database, the instance size, the ebs volume size, etc. etc.

There is obviously a lot that goes into load testing, and it is beyond the scope of this answer.